# How to export .f3d files for flare3d?

Tags: actionscript-3, blender, stage3d, flare3d

What program / method exports  .f3d file ?

I have blender made 3d model and want to export convert into .f3d file for use with flare3d.

(tried to use 3dsMax 2010 exporter but it only exports to .zf3d...and I need .f3d)

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might try to find an older version of Flare3D IDE and exporter. However, as far as I know .zf3d is a standard now for Flare3D engine.

Answer (score 0):

.f3d is a new format of flare3d model file
it supported by 2.8 IDE

firstly you make .f3dProject file
secondary you convert .f3dProject into .f3d